# C99 command-line does not print anything in this C programming case

Tags: c, pointers, struct, c99

I'm experiencing a weird problem with C today. Have a quick look at this simplified code snippet:

```
typedef struct
{
    /* The number of index terms */
    int nTerms;
    /* Information about each index term */
    TERMINFO *terms;
} INDEX;

INDEX *buildIndex(char *termsfile, char *dirs[], int n, OPTIONS opts)
{
    INDEX *ind = NULL;
    ind->nTerms = 5;
    return ind;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    ... // declare and assign values for TERMFILE, DIRS and opts.
    INDEX *ind = buildIndex(TERMFILE, DIRS, sizeof(DIRS), opts); // LINE A 
    printf("Does NOT print %d\n",ind->nTerms); // LINE B
    printf("Does NOT print as well"); // LINE C
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile this program, there is no errors occurred, however when I run the compiled file, it doesn't print anything to the commmand-line (I'm using PuTTy on Windows machine). It becomes even weird when I remove the line `LINE A` and `LINE B`, then LINE C can be printed.

In short, whatever goes after LINE A can't be printed out (or executed?).

I don't know if there is any problem with my code.

Comment: Is your second `LINE A` meant to be `LINE B`?

Comment: oops sorry, someone edited it for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the second line you are dereferencing a `NULL` pointer, which leads to undefined behaviour:

```
INDEX *ind = NULL;
ind->nTerms = 5;
return ind;
```

You need to make `ind` point to non-local memory, i.e. allocate it from the heap with `malloc`, or set it to point to a variable with global lifetime:

```
INDEX *ind = malloc(sizeof(INDEX));

if (ind != NULL)
    ind->nTerms = 5;

return ind;
```

The responsibility for freeing the returned struct (and not dereferencing it if it's NULL) is delegated to the caller in this case.

Note that if you were to set `ind` to point to a locally-declared variable and return it, UB will occur whenever the caller attempts to dereference the pointer, because the stack is restored after the function terminates.

Comment: +1 Undefined behavior which is most likely a crash in this case.

Comment: +1 undefined behaviour but _without_ insisting that it crashes. Running to completion but without outputting anything is perfectly acceptable as UB. So is the machine collapsing in on itself to form a naked singularity. **Anything** can happen!

Comment: @Blagovest, I made some minor tweaks to handle malloc errors, hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 4):

The reason why it isn't printing anything is because it's crashing:

```
INDEX *ind = NULL;
ind->nTerms = 5;
```

You're dereferencing a NULL. (which is undefined behavior)

When you remove LINE A and LINE B, it doesn't crash so it prints LINE C. (you also forgot the `\n` in LINE C to flush the buffer.)

What you need to do it dynamically allocate `ind` via malloc and return. (and be sure to free it later)

```
INDEX *buildIndex(char *termsfile, char *dirs[], int n, OPTIONS opts)
{
    INDEX *ind = malloc(sizeof(INDEX));   //  Allocate

    //  You may wish to check if `ind == NULL` to see if the allocation failed.

    ind->nTerms = 5;
    return ind;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    ... // declare and assign values for TERMFILE, DIRS and opts.
    INDEX *ind = buildIndex(TERMFILE, DIRS, sizeof(DIRS), opts); // LINE A 
    printf("Does NOT print %d\n",ind->nTerms); // LINE B
    printf("Does NOT print as well"); // LINE C

    free(ind);  //  Free

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that allocating an object in a function and freeing it in another part of the program is generally discouraged. You could allocate your pointer in the *main*, pass it as an argument to `buildIndex()`, and `free()` it in the main.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be in buildIndex

```
INDEX *buildIndex(char *termsfile, char *dirs[], int n, OPTIONS opts) 
{
    INDEX *ind = NULL;
    ind->nTerms = 5;
    return ind; 
}
```

As you can see, you set `ind` to `NULL` and then try to reference to immediately afterwards. That's undefined behavior, so anything could happen next.

Answer (score 0):

You call the function `buildIndex` which contains these two lines.

> INDEX *ind = NULL;
>   ind->nTerms = 5;

So you are dereferencing the null pointer. This is erroneous. Your program crashes, so don't run any further.